# Using Meteor.users.findOne in Method If Statement

Tags: meteor

I have a handlebars helper below that shows me the selected players threat. And it works.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('sthreat', function() {
    var sthreat = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Session.get('selectedPlayer')}, {threat: 1});
    return sthreat;
});
```

However the button below (on client) and method (on server) are suppose to check that the player has 5 or more threat before proceeding, though they're not working.

```
'click input.increment': function(){
  var selectedThreat = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Session.get('selectedPlayer')}, {threat: 1});
  Meteor.call('incclick',selectedThreat);
},

incclick: function (selectedThreat) {
  if(selectedThreat <= 4) {
  } else {
  Meteor.users.update({_id: Session.get('selectedPlayer')}, {$inc: {'threat': -5}});
  Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId}, {$inc: {'threat': 5}});
  }
},
```

I figured if I could get the value to show in a helper, I should be able to use it in an equation. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.users.findOne` will return a document. You passed in `{threat: 1}` as options, but they will be ignored since none of them are valid. Options like `sort`, `field` and `limit` would work.

I think you're looking to get an attribute of the document. The result of Meteor.users.findOne will be something like this

```
{
    _id : ..
    threat: 3,
    ...
}
```

So you can just pass the attribute to the method instead of the entire document:

```
Meteor.call('incclick',selectedThreat.threat);
```

Comment: When I did it like this it had an error. Error invoking Method 'incclick': Internal server error [500]

Comment: @JonPotts This is due to an unrelated Error in your method call. You should check your Server side console for details. I suspect it's the `Session` which is not supported server side.